Is it possible to run R8 optimization and dexguard obfuscation and security together?
We use dexguard for security reasons. But R8 has lots of optimization for android runtime, compose and kotlin. We think we are missing out those optimization with dexguard.
Is it possible to run both tools. Like first R8 optimization without any code removals or obfuscation. Then run dexguard for security?

You can try to run R8 with -dontobfuscate and the run DexGuard afterwards with the excat same rules except for the -dontobfuscate, to see what happens (with DEX size and performance). Running optimizations without code removals is not really possible as the two are tied together. Not sure what your build system is, but you might have to  experiment using command line tools.

That is what I wanna do but I am not sure if their inputs and outputs match. that is the part I am puzzled. And I am not sure at which stage they need to be run as most of their integration is automated and not documented much.

You could try a compiler dump from AGP. That gives all input to R8, and from there you can use R8 and DexGuard from the command line. Then you can try replace the DEX in an existing APK (unsigned or something you can sign again) to see what happens. If you are also enabling resource shrinking in AGP you could get into additional issues, so initially you should probably leave that out.
